# how can I prevent multiple login from same user id from different browsers in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

How to prevent this situation when a user has already logged in from one browser and tries to log in into wordpress again with the same user id but from a different web browser? 
One login per ip address also does not solve the problem if a user access the site from mobile and a laptop simultaneously.

Comment: I do not implement this, this is just an idea: when a user login, create a websocket, to check, is his browser is communicate with your server. Insert a row into the wp_options table, what is tells to the wp, user has logged in. So, you can check this flag any time, when somebody is try to login. If user logged out, then set this flag to false. For this, you need to write a websocket server. Here is an example: http://www.binarytides.com/websockets-php-tutorial/

Maybe others will have better idea(s).

Answer (score 1):

create a plugin or place it under `function.php`. here is the refrence [wordpress one session per user](http://benmay.org/wordpress/single-user-wordpress/)

and the code is

```
<?php
/*
Plugin name: Single user login
Plugin URI: 
Description:
Author: Ben May
Author URI: 
Version: 0.1
*/

if( !class_exists( 'WPSingleUserLoggin' ) )
{
    class WPSingleUserLoggin
    {
        private $session_id; 

        function __construct()
        {
            if ( ! session_id() )
                session_start();

            $this->session_id = session_id();

            add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'init' ) );
            add_action( 'wp_login', array( $this, 'wp_login' ), 10, 2 );
        }

        function init()
        {
            if( ! is_user_logged_in() )
                return;

            $stored_sess_id = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_wp_single_user_hash', true );

            if( $stored_sess_id != $this->session_id )
            {
                wp_logout(); 
                wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
                exit;
            }
        }
        function wp_login( $user_login, $user )
        {
            update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_wp_single_user_hash', $this->session_id );
            return;
        }
    }
    new WPSingleUserLoggin();
}
```

**UPDATE**

it will autometically destroy the old session .

if you want to change the functionality do your stuff in

```
if( $stored_sess_id != $this->session_id )
 {
   wp_logout(); 
   wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
   exit;
 }
```

and this function

```
function wp_login( $user_login, $user )
{
update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_wp_single_user_hash', $this->session_id );
 return;
}
```